# Postfix Hostname Change mailbox issues

Tags: 20.04, postfix, virtualmin

Please excuse my ignorance.

I changed the my server name and the hostname my domain was example.com and now it is example.ie

When I send an email to one of my email addresses something@example.ie I get this message in postfix

to=something-example.com@example.com, orig_to=something@example.ie, relay=local, delay=0.1, delays=0.09/0/0/0, dsn=5.1.1, status=bounced (unknown user: "something-example.com")

I changed everything that I could find. I have other domains that work, the main domain is the only one that doesn`t work.

Thank you very much for your support.

Love you people

Comment: Without seeing your code that is sending the email and without seeing your mail server configuration files, it's impossible to really answer this.  It looks like, however, your email is not being processed properly and directing to an incorrect domain - we need to see all your configurations for Postfix to really determine what's going on here.

Comment: @ThomasWard main.cf would be enough ? or what else can I provide to make this clear

Comment: main.cf should be sufficient unless you have any customizations in master.cf or such.  but we also need to see how you're crafting the email that's being handed off to your SMTP server as well.